# Python Dash Empty Table

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I use Dash and I want to display a Table, the html.Layout is like this :

```
html.Div([
     dash_table.DataTable(
          id="table_infos",
          columns=["Intitulé", "Donnée"]
            )
        ], style={'display': 'inline-block', 'verticalAlign': 'top', 'width': '30%', 'padding':'30px'})
```

And my callback is like this:

```
@app.callback(Output('table_infos', 'data'),
                [Input('ville-picker', 'value')])
def update_generales(selected_ville):
    departement = df.loc[df['ville'] == selected_ville]['departement'].iloc[0]
    region = df.loc[df['ville'] == selected_ville]['region'].iloc[0]
    cp = df.loc[df['ville'] == selected_ville]['code postale'].iloc[0]
    code_insee = df.loc[df['ville'] == selected_ville]['code_insee'].iloc[0][-5:]
    ci = df.loc[df['ville'] == selected_ville]['code_insee'].iloc[0][18:]

    habitants = df_demo.loc[df_demo['code_insee'] == ci]['Population'].iloc[0]

    infos = {'Intitulé' : ['Région','Département','Code Postal', 'Code Insee',"Nombre d'habitants"],
            'Donnée' : [region, departement, cp, code_insee, habitants]}

    df_info = pd.DataFrame(infos, columns=['Intitulé', 'Donnée'])

    df_info['Intitulé'] = np.asarray(['Région','Département','Code Postal', 'Code Insee',"Nombre d'habitants"])
    data = df_info.to_dict("rows")

    return data
```

However, I have an empty Table, but with the same number of rows I wished and 2 columns as I wished, But empty Table.

Someone can help me please !

Comment: Why are you creating a dict of your data, but then putting it into a dataframe, renaming the columns to the same thing, and then setting one of those renamed columns to the same data? Either way, that shouldn't be your issue, but it's weird. You don't show your code for the ville picker. Maybe the issue is there? The table will only be updated when the ville picker has a new value.

Comment: The columns need to be more than just a list of strings. You need a list of `dict`s with a `name` and `id` value in each `dict`. Try `columns=[{'id': "Intitulé", 'name': "Intitulé"}, {'id': "Donnée", 'name': "Donnée"}]`

Comment: the code with the ville picker is okay because I have other graphs and data who are updating when I change the ville (city)

Comment: @coralvanda thank you very much, it works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way `columns` was being defined. It must have both the `name` and `id` values, like this:

`columns=[{'id': "Intitulé", 'name': "Intitulé"}, {'id': "Donnée", 'name': "Donnée"}]`

[Docs page](https://dash.plot.ly/datatable/reference) for reference.